# Any way for a primary key violation within an insert with multiple values to proceed with the valid values?

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb, sql-insert

Assuming I run an insert with a comma separated list of values for performance purposes (generally inserting 200 at a time) and the field 'id' is set as the primary key.

By default, executing the below:

```
Insert into table(id, somefield) values (1,'foo'),(2,'bar'),(1,'foo'),(3,'bob')
```

This whole insert would fail.

Is there a behavior, pragma, setting or other I can use that will allow the first two and the third inserts to succeed?

Comment: You mean `INSERT IGNORE`?

Answer (score 0):

You could use `insert ignore`:

```
insert ignore into mytable (id, somefield) 
values (1,'foo'),(2,'bar'),(1,'foo'),(3,'bob')
```

As explained [in the documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/insert.html):

> If you use the IGNORE modifier, ignorable errors that occur while executing the INSERT statement are ignored. For example, without IGNORE, a row that duplicates an existing UNIQUE index or PRIMARY KEY value in the table causes a duplicate-key error and the statement is aborted. With IGNORE, the row is discarded and no error occurs. Ignored errors generate warnings instead.

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=b5efaf430abb84491699dd3bd3c9f4a8)**:

```
create table t (id int primary key, somefield varchar(10))

insert into t(id, somefield) 
values (1,'foo'),(2,'bar'),(1,'foo'),(3,'bob');
-- error: Duplicate entry '1' for key 't.PRIMARY'

select * from t;

id | somefield
-: | :--------

insert ignore into t(id, somefield) 
values (1,'foo'),(2,'bar'),(1,'foo'),(3,'bob');

select * from t;

id | somefield
-: | :--------
 1 | foo      
 2 | bar      
 3 | bob
```